# Sobre poner imagenes CSS

Tags: html, css

Quiero lograr este efecto de poner solo la mitad de una imagen de "perfil" sobre otra que sea un "banner"[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

no creo que sea de utilidad pero este es el codigo con el que estuve intentando lograrlo, la logro superponer pero no logro manipularla para dejarla donde yo quiero:

```
        <div class="images">
            <img src="assets/img/12.jpg" class="img-banner img-fluid">
            <img src="assets/img/foto-perfil.jpg" class="img-perfil">
        </div>

    </section>
 
.images{
 position: relative;
}

.img-banner{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -10;
}

.img-perfil{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img-banner` No es necesario que tenga posición absoluta, en cambio  `img-perfil` si lo necesita.

Luego el asunto es muy simple, a `img-banner` debes asignar la propiedad `bottom` en negativo y NO ocupar `top`

```css
.img-banner {
 background-color:blue;
}
.img-perfil {
 background-color:red;
}


.images{
 position: relative;
}

.img-banner{
   width: 100%;
   height:260px;
}

.img-perfil{
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    bottom: -50px;
    left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="assets/img/12.jpg" class="img-banner img-fluid">
  <img src="assets/img/foto-perfil.jpg" class="img-perfil">
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias! me venia quemado las pestañas hace horas y era mas facil de lo que pensaba